# Touchpad not working in my asus X556UF. i'm using ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: nvidia, touchpad, asus, lts

im using asus X556UF, intel i5-6200u processor with nvidia 930m.

i'm searching the entire internet and did not find any answers for my touchpad. i'm installing this ubuntu with dual boot for my windows 10. i did try to do this three:

1.`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/focaltech-dkms`

2.`sudo apt-get update`

3.`sudo apt-get install focaltech-dkms`

but it gave me:

E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/hanipouspilot/focaltech-dkms/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

when run sudo apt-get update command in one of the lines.

also, xinput list gives me:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ USB Camera                                id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Asus WMI hotkeys                          id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

can someone help me? i'm new to ubuntu. (sorry for my bad english)

Comment: Your touchpad is not detected by the system. Focaltech touchpads are supported by linux kernel and you do not need to install drivers. But you do not have a Focaltech touchpad, at least a supported one.

Comment: so, what can i do to make the touchpad detected by the system?

Comment: I do not think that you can do something with that. Most likely a new driver is needed to be written, or some support should be added to existing kernel drivers. Your touchpad is not supported yet.

Comment: What does `dmesg | grep pnp` show?

Comment: [    0.390439] pnp: PnP ACPI init
[    0.390848] pnp 00:01: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0b00 (active)
[    0.391044] pnp 00:04: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs ATK3001 PNP030b (active)
[    0.393404] pnp: PnP ACPI: found 9 devices
[    1.000391] i8042: PNP: PS/2 appears to have AUX port disabled, if this is incorrect please boot with i8042.nopnp

Answer (score 0):

I have the same laptop and had the same problem

1. Run

   ```
   sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub
   ```

   In the open window edit line

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
   ```

   it should look this way

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i8042.nopnp"
   ```

   Save file and run

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```
2. Run

   ```
   echo "blacklist i2c_hid" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/i2c-hid.conf
   sudo depmod -a
   sudo update-initramfs -u
   echo "synaptics_i2c" | sudo tee -a /etc/modules
   ```
3. Reboot.

   What it does is, it removes the synaptics hid drivers from the blacklist and allows them to be loaded at the initialization of the RAM file system, allowing your touchpad to work at boot.

Comment: after doing the steps you gave, now, when i type xinput it gave me  ' ⎜   ↳ Elan Touchpad                            id=11 [slave  pointer  (2)]
  '  it doesn't there before, but still my touchpad didnt working

Comment: can i know the version of bios that you are using. in my case, im using version 405